# How to make dips harder?

Tags: calisthenics, resistancetraining, dips

I have been doing dips for a long time now and they start to get too easy. Right now, I can do many reps on traditional dips so the exercise gets a little boring. Therefore, I am looking for a way to make dips more challenging so that I only work with low reps.

I am aware that weighted dip is a solution. But, this is not an option for me, so I am looking for something else.

What I have tried thus far are Archer dips. However, my shoulder joints did not like the movement at all, so this is not an option. And, I made my reps at times slower while at other times faster but progress like this is hard to measure so I am not considering this.

Note that I only want a progression of the dips that focuses on my pectorals alone. There are other ways to make dips harder, like for example, dips in the L-sit position, but this doesn't add more resistance to the pectorals. It makes the overall move harder so I don't want this. Also, it seems that single-arm dips focus more on the triceps rather than pectorals while I am looking for a movement that is dominated by pectoral muscle work.

So what are some dips progressions that I can to do add more resistance and make this exercise harder for my pectorals?

Comment: Why are weighted dips not an option?

Comment: It's not at all clear what sort of dips you are doing at the moment - are you using dipping bars, a TRX-style suspension system, or just bodyweight dips off a step or similar?

Comment: If adding weight isn't an option (can you explain why?) the only thing I can come up with is to add time under tension. Go down in 4 seconds, hold it at the bottom for 2, and go back up in 4 seconds is an example of this. Or doing dips on rings instead of bars. There aren't many other things you can do on a bodyweight exercise like this if adding weight isn't an option.

Comment: I am doing bodyweight dips on parallel bars and looking for a variation of dips that is harder. I don't want to add weight because due to my job I travel a lot and it would be hard to keep track of progress and also I admit that I find it quite boring to load a bag with weights rather than just jumping staright at the dips bars and workout.

Comment: You kind of need to pick your poison here. You didn't enjoy a variation, don't want to add weight, don't want to increase volume (stay low rep), and found tempo work inconsistent. Those are really all your variables. So where are you willing to concede something?

Comment: C. Lange I am looking for a dip variation, for every other exercise that I do I was able to find a harder variation like for example, pull ups to single arm pull ups, squats to pistol squats, bodyweight rows to front lever pulls, etc. But for dips I haven't found a good variation.